# product buying option(Add to cart functionality) for only one category products

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on a project which has a category.

And I want to add product buying option only for that category products.
Other categories don't have product buying options.

I want to know the best way to implement this.
Please explain in detail.

Comment: product buying option ???

Comment: Means add to cart functionality for category products.

Answer (score 1):

You can user observer the **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add** event.

`<config>
    [...]
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_module_add_product>
                        <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                        <method>logCartAdd</method>
                    </namespace_module_add_product>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    [...]
</config>`

Create New observer class php file

`class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
   public function logCartAdd($observer)
   {
        $categoryId = "YOUR_CATEGORY_ID";
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->load(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0));
        if (!$product->getId()) {
            return;
        }
        $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if (!in_array($categoryId, $categories) {
             Mage::throwException('Your Error Message');
        }
   }
}`

OR

You can add condition in template file

`app/design/frontend/[template]/[package]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

`<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$requirelogincategory = [ID of the category that requires login];
$buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart');
$categoryId = "YOUR_CATEGORY_ID";
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
if (in_array($categoryId, $categories): 
    if($_product->isSaleable()): 
?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    endif;
else:
?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Write Error Message Here');?></p>
<?php
endif; 
?>`